# using SVM for binary classification

Tags: svm

I am using sVM-light for binary classification.and I am using SVM in the learning mode. 
I have my train.dat file ready.but when i run this command ,instead of creating file model ,it writes somethings in terminal:

my command:

./svm_learn   example1/train.dat example1/model
output:

Scanning examples...done
Reading examples into memory...Feature numbers must be larger or equal to 1!!!
: Success
LINE:   -1   0:1.0  6:1.0   16:1.0  18:1.0  28:1.0  29:1.0  31:1.0  48:1.0  58:1.0  73:1.0  82:1.0  93:1.0  95:1.0  106:1.0 108:1.0 118:1.0 121:1.0 122:1.0151:1.0  164:1.0 167:1.0 169:1.0 170:1.0 179:1.0 190:1.0 193:1.0 220:1.0 237:1.0250:1.0  252:1.0 267:1.0 268:1.0 269:1.0 278:1.0 283:1.0 291:1.0 300:1.0 305:1.0320:1.0  332:1.0 336:1.0 342:1.0 345:1.0 348:1.0 349:1.0 350:1.0 368:1.0 370:1.0384:1.0  390:1.0 394:1.0 395:1.0 396:1.0 397:1.0 400:1.0 401:1.0 408:1.0 416:1.0427:1.0  433:1.0 435:1.0 438:1.0 441:1.0 446:1.0 456:1.0 471:1.0 485:1.0 510:1.0523:1.0  525:1.0 526:1.0 532:1.0 540:1.0 553:1.0 567:1.0 568:1.0 581:1.0 583:1.0604:1.0  611:1.0 615:1.0 616:1.0 618:1.0 623:1.0 624:1.0 626:1.0 651:1.0 659:1.0677:1.0  678:1.0 683:1.0 690:1.0 694:1.0 699:1.0 713:1.0 714:1.0 720:1.0 722:1.0731:1.0  738:1.0 755:1.0 761:1.0 763:1.0 768:1.0 776:1.0 782:1.0 792:1.0 817:1.0823:1.0  827:1.0 833:1.0 834:1.0 838:1.0 842:1.0 848:1.0 851:1.0 863:1.0 867:1.0890:1.0  900:1.0 903:1.0 923:1.0 935:1.0 942:1.0 946:1.0 947:1.0 949:1.0 956:1.0962:1.0  965:1.0 968:1.0 983:1.0 986:1.0 987:1.0 990:1.0 998:1.0 1007:1.0    1014:1.0    1019:1.0    1022:1.0    1024:1.0    1029:1.0    1030:1.01032:1.0    1047:1.0    1054:1.0    1063:1.0    1069:1.0    1076:1.0    1085:1.0    1093:1.0    1098:1.0    1108:1.0    1109:1.01116:1.0    1120:1.0    1133:1.0    1134:1.0    1135:1.0    1138:1.0    1139:1.0    1144:1.0    1146:1.0    1148:1.0    1149:1.01161:1.0    1165:1.0    1169:1.0    1170:1.0    1177:1.0    1187:1.0    1194:1.0    1212:1.0    1214:1.0    1239:1.0    1243:1.01251:1.0    1257:1.0    1274:1.0    1278:1.0    1292:1.0    1297:1.0    1304:1.0    1319:1.0    1324:1.0    1325:1.0    1353:1.01357:1.0    1366:1.0    1374:1.0    1379:1.0    1392:1.0    1394:1.0    1407:1.0    1412:1.0    1414:1.0    1419:1.0    1433:1.01435:1.0    1437:1.0    1453:1.0    1463:1.0    1464:1.0    1469:1.0    1477:1.0    1481:1.0    1487:1.0    1506:1.0    1514:1.01519:1.0    1526:1.0    1536:1.0    1549:1.0    1551:1.0    1553:1.0    1561:1.0    1569:1.0    1578:1.0    1603:1.0    1610:1.01615:1.0    1617:1.0    1625:1.0    1638:1.0    1646:1.0    1663:1.0    1666:1.0    1672:1.0    1681:1.0    1690:1.0    1697:1.01699:1.0    1706:1.0    1708:1.0    1717:1.0    1719:1.0    1732:1.0    1737:1.0    1756:1.0    1766:1.0    1771:1.0    1789:1.01804:1.0    1805:1.0    1808:1.0    1814:1.0    1815:1.0    1820:1.0    1824:1.0    1832:1.0    1841:1.0    1844:1.0    1852:1.01861:1.0    1875:1.0    1899:1.0    1902:1.0    1904:1.0    1905:1.0    1917:1.0    1918:1.0    1919:1.0    1921:1.0    1926:1.01934:1.0    1937:1.0    1942:1.0    1956:1.0    1965:1.0    1966:1.0    1970:1.0    1971:1.0    1980:1.0    1995:1.0    2000:1.02009:1.0    2010:1.0    2012:1.0    2015:1.0    2018:1.0    2022:1.0    2047:1.0    2076:1.0    2082:1.0    2095:1.0    2108:1.02114:1.0    2123:1.0    2130:1.0    2133:1.0    2141:1.0    2142:1.0    2143:1.0    2148:1.0    2157:1.0    2160:1.0    2162:1.02170:1.0    2195:1.0    2199:1.0    2201:1.0    2202:1.0    2205:1.0    2211:1.0    2218:1.0

I dont know what to do.

p.s.when i make my train.dat very shorter ,everything works fine!!!

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so that we can try it out and help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

From what I could interpret from the log, your training set has an issue.

The first few characters of the training row that has issue are
`-1 0:1.0 6:1.0`

The issue is not with the size but with feature indexing. You are starting your feature index at 0 (0:1) whereas `svmlight` requires that all feature index be equal or greater than 1.

Change the indexing to start at 1 and it should work fine.

Comment: Also as far as  I know, SVMlight requires a non-zero class label (the first value which is included in the beginning of a line). If you have a class labelled as 0, you may need to change it, which is not the case for this specific problem btw.